# Ubuntu 18.04 shutdown after pressing login button

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell 5000 Gaming Series, The installation goes fine then it prompt Restart after installation.
After restart login screen appear i put the password (for my created account during installation) and hit enter, but the screen goes pink and few seconds later it automatically shutdown without showing anything.
I reinstall the Ubuntu but this time it gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the splashscreen from GRUB as described [here](https://www.96boards.org/documentation/enterprise/developerbox/installation/ubuntu.html#first-boot-disable-splash-screen) (I would suggest removing `quiet splash`) and then see if some error pops up.

Also this website is meant for programming questions; please try something like [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) next time.

Comment: I tried removing 'splash' and 'quiet splash' but i gives the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18.04 shortcut is (alt+ctrl+k).